# Owl carousel not responsive at all

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

Im working on [website](http://www.daklapackmedia.com/karimtest)

And as you can see I have the carousel further down the page but its not responsive at all, how can I get this responsive and have the items in the same position?

Comment: i didn't see any `carousel`

Comment: @Amitsingh its beneath the header our services

Comment: Why do you have `padding/margin` on the inner items (like `#item1 { margin-left: 605px; }` or `#item4 { padding-top: 480px; margin-left: -913px; }`. I think that this is the problem. Anyway, this also causes a problem in desktop too.

Comment: @MoshFeu i did that so i could have them positioned like they are in the design, and i would like to have them positioned like that but also be responsive

Comment: So use `media query` to detect mobile devices and use percentages for the position in mobile (to be responsive)